# Getting image overlap with border in Visualforce page. How to avoid it?

Tags: visualforce, css, html

[image]

As you can see the blue color header image is overlapping with my border on the top of the page both sides how to avoid it.
Here is the style i have used-

```
<style>
 html{
 border: 3px solid black;
 }
 .header
 {
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: absolute;
  margin:0 auto;
  left:0;
  top:0;
 }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser dev tools to help you out with styling work. Right-click on the image on your page and select "Inspect" element, to have a glance on the **Style** (right side panel) of various attributes on your page.

[image]

You can either reduce/increase your image width, add padding or use broder-image tag to fit the image

adding border to image -https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-add-border-to-image-in-css.html